# Having issues with HSQLDB compatibility with postgres

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hsqldb, dbunit

My Postgres query involves `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.

Query:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COL1 = 'C1' WHERE COL2 IN 
(SELECT COL2 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL3 = 'C3' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED)
```

Using HSQLDB for testing. It does not have `FOR UPDATE` support. Upgraded from HSQLDB2 = 2.2 to 2.3.3 to 2.4.0. But with no success. Please suggest some workaround or am I missing something.

Added this as well:

```
sql.syntax pgs=true;
```

Exception encountered:

> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.update(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE TABLE_NAME set COL1
>   = ? where COL2 in (select COL2 from TABLE_NAME where COL3 = ? limit ? FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED)]; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: FOR required: ) at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:82)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:655)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:937)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:942)
>   at Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: FOR
>   required: ) at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:387)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1530)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
>   Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: FOR required: )
>   at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedTokenRequire(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserBase.readThis(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadInPredicateRightPart(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadPredicateRightPart(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadBooleanPrimaryOrNull(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadBooleanTestOrNull(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadBooleanFactorOrNull(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadBooleanTermOrNull(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadBooleanValueExpression(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileUpdateStatement(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

If the `sql.syntax pgs=true;` you mentioned is a URL property, it should have
 an underscore, not a space, like so:
`sql.syntax_pgs=true;`

However, if you want to set compatibility mode as a database query you can execute: 
`SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE`

Answer (score -1):

This query syntax is specific to PostgreSQL row locking support. You can modify the query for HSQLDB as:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COL1 = 'C1' WHERE COL2 IN 
(SELECT COL2 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL3 = 'C3' LIMIT 1)
```

In fact, this simplified query does the same thing in HSQLDB, but may have different outcomes when used with PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COL1 = 'C1' WHERE COL3 = 'C3'
```